# Saving Files to user Computer in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, export-to-csv

I have look for days, with no luck.

Can anyone tell me how to save files in VB.Net to any computer? There are lost of articles, but those only tell you about saving to your own computer by giving folder access, not a random user's computer.

You can see my example here http://hanontest.com/POShellCreator.aspx (You have to enter text into task code, project id and notes field, then click create. Then click export, you will see the error.)

I can go to a local Pizza shop website and download a menu pdf, I know its possible.

In my example it saves when you click the button, I would like a save as dialog if anyone knows how to do that as well.

Here is the save string:

```
  Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now()
        Dim strDate As String = regDate.ToString(".yyyy\.MM\.dd")
        TextBox5.Text = "c:\temp\" & Vendor & "&" & Vendor2 & "&" & Vendor3 & "&" & Vendor4 & TaskEmpty & strDate & ".csv"
```

Here is how I am saving:

```
 Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    'Define Path to save file.
    Dim path As String = TextBox5.Text

    ' Create or overwrite the file. 
    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

    ' Add text to the file. 
    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(TextBox3.Text)
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET web application then your server-side code can't save a file directly to the machine of someone viewing your site in their browser.  They have to actually download the file from a URL.  That URL might be an actual file on the server that you save or it might just be data generated on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing there is because you're attempting to save the text file to the *server's*
 file system, which you don't have write access to.

To return a file to user from the server you need to do a little more work, and it's not going to simple on a postback from a button.

You need to send the data down to the client in the `Response.OutputStream`, instead of your page, and also tell the browser to treat it as a file download:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=textFile.csv");
```

Comment: The current page saves to my c: drive like I want, it is not saving to the server...... The error is that when I publish to a server it comes up with that error when I try to save to c: drive.

Comment: Hmm, that's not what the error on the site you've linked to is saying. It's trying to write to `C:\temp\` **on the server**. When you run it locally it probably does save it to you computer because it is running as you, but on the server, when I ran it, I got an error when trying to write to the servers disk. You cannot write directly to the user's filesystem without a save dialog. When I read the question initially I thought your problem was that the browser was showing the text file inline...